# Nativescript mapserver maps

Tags: nativescript, mapserver

Any ideas how to start with MapServer with NativeScript. I don't have necessary skills yet to make own plugin but I must try if nothing else is found.

Does anyone know any resources to get started implementing mapserver maps for nativescript. Plugin, code anything.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have an application using NativeScript framework and you want to include some map services from MapServer.

If that is the case, you may not need to write your own plugin but you still do some level of coding to achieve the goal.

My recommendation would be :

1) At your front end, choose a GIS map library such as Google maps API, Leaflet or OpenLayers API. The GIS library would handle a lot of critical tasks in the process such as handling communication with GIS server, user interface function etc. So that you don't have to reinvent the wheels again.

https://developers.google.com/maps/

2) Based on your system requirement, you may or may not need a GIS server such as MapServer. Data could come from directly from clients for example. But since you mentioned it i would think you may need a GIS server to publish some data for the application to consume the services.
MapServer services via OGC standard protocols are easy to integred with most of the popular GIS libraries mentioned earlier. So once you publish Map service (wms) for example, it would be as easy as add one layer in such GIS library point to the service endpoint you published via Http request and by passing some parameters you would be able to get the GIS contents.

This is the link about how to consume MapServer service on the client side:
http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_client.html